# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "null" (type string) at path "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So when I try to make a new post, and then delete it without reloading the page, I can't and I get this error. I'm new to mongodb and this is my all first app MEAN-like
This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Post = require("../models/post");

const app = express();

mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://Milos:re0zygTSPZjXGpAB@cluster0.ijb8l.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database!");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Connection failed!");
  });

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

app.post("/api/posts", (req, res, next) => {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    content: req.body.content,
  });
  post.save();
  res.status(201).json({
    message: "Post added successfully",
  });
});
app.get("/api/posts", (req, res, next) => {
  Post.find().then((documents) => {
    console.log(documents);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
      posts: documents,
    });
  });
});

app.delete("/api/posts/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Post deleted!" });
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

And here is my deletePost function

```
 deletePost(postId: string) {
    this.http
      .delete('http://localhost:3000/api/posts/' + postId)
      .subscribe(() => {
        const updatedPosts = this.posts.filter(post => post.id !== postId);
        this.posts = updatedPosts;
        this.postsUpdated.next([...this.posts]);
      });
  }
```

I get that error and when I reload the page it all works fine. But I don't need a page reload, I need it all to work in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because mongoose try to cast `id` value to `Object(_id)` field so that it can properly query for the matching doc. This is an ObjectId but "null" is not a valid ObjectId so the cast fails.

```
// the id here is null, try passing valid id and it will 
// delete the specific doc
//Also, use catch blocks to catch errors after all thens
// or create a global handler for it
app.delete("/api/posts/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  Post.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Post deleted!" });
  }).catch(console.error);
});
```